# Correct spelling in [shippment-tracking] tag

Tags: bug, tags

The tag [shippment-tracking](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shippment-tracking) is quite popular (61 questions at the time of writing), but it seems to have been created by a user without spelling checker. Could one of the ♦ moderators correct this to [shipment-tracking], please? I believe there's no option for normal users to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's done. now [shippment-tracking](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shippment-tracking)  redirects to [shipment-tracking](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shipment-tracking).

Answer (score 1):

> I believe there's no option for normal users to do this.

Yes, There is no chance to correct the spelling of that specific tag by normal users.

To intimate to the moderators about such type of tags,

**Flag the question to the moderator which contains that incorrect spelling tag.**

Then the moderator will take action sure.

**Edit :**

Now its done. Please check once.